# Get more than 50 users from Instagram API endpoint /users/search

Tags: api, endpoint, instagram-api

I'm working on a java application that requires getting all users from Instagram's api endpoint /users/search that match a given name.  The maximum number of user objects returned seems to be 50. I created an instagram profile for a common name to test this, and I call it with:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=Common%20Name&client_id=CLIENT-ID
```

Which returns a list of 50 profiles that have matching/similar full names and usernames.  The profile I created is not among them.  I know it exists, however, because I am the one who created it and I can still access it with the specific id using:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER-ID/?client_id=CLIENT-ID
```

Some of the instagram endpoints have pagination, which would make this easy, but this endpoint does not.  Is there a consistent method to find ALL users with a matching/similar full name to the one provided in the `/users/search` endpoint?